# How to play fullscreen video using surfaceview?

Tags: android, video, surfaceview

I am playing a local mp4 video using surfaceview here is the layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</SurfaceView>

</FrameLayout>
```

from code i am setting the full screen to surfaceview

```
    int height = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); //metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); //metrics.widthPixels;

    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

    mPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    //holder.setFixedSize(width, height);
    holder.setSizeFromLayout();
```

But, Now the problem is that video is not playing in full screen there is black screen above the video.

screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4sTM.png 
How can I play full screen video ?

Comment: Can you tell me why you are setting size dynamically... you have already set correct parameters in your xml layout. In your oncreate function if you will set full screen flag then it will automatically set your layout as full screen without setting size at runtime. I think there is some problem related to width and height. Can you try by setting full screen flag only.

Comment: thanks for your comments but setting the flag has no effect.

Comment: it is not making as full screen or video is not starting.

Comment: I dont know is it mistake or intentionally you are doing but you are allocating width as height you are using  int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

Comment: wait a minute I am giving you a screenshot.

Comment: here is the screenshot http://i.imgur.com/WNFDM.png

Comment: hey it is playing but your width and height both are coming equal....

Answer (score 5):

Dont know how old this is..
try this one

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

before doing the setContentView on the onCreate method of your activity

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
  LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    mPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    holder.setSizeFromLayout();
```

Comment: Is there any way i can strach video to full screen even it is not a HD video?

Comment: yes. even if it is not a HD video, using these the video will play in full screen only

Comment: @BharatSharma Yes. Removing the setLayoutParams(lp) also displays the video in fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
            mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
            holder = mPreview.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
```

Do not set width and height at all... in your oncreate

Comment: here full screen does not mean that i want to remove notification bar or title bar.

Comment: I have tried different video (HD) and it is playing in full screen :). Is there any way i can strach video to full screen even it is not a HD video?

Comment: That i have never tried but in my case it always set it automatically according to surface size. If you have solution of this then please post it or give me a clue in comment.